# Rolling Percentile - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation, percentile

This gives Percentile Values for a column below,

```
df[column].rank(pct=True)
```

But is there a way to get the rolling percentile Values for a column by using this similar method, without writing functions or loops and longer code? Currently when adding the `.rolling(window)`, it is not working.

If there is not, Pandas desperately needs to add this as a feature for the `.rolling()`, it is there for `.quantile()`, it makes no sense to not have it for the percentiles as well.

Comment: [Rolling rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.rank.html) will be [added in 1.4.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.4.0.html#rank-function-for-rolling-and-expanding-windows). Not helpful at the moment since this is not yet released, but it is upcoming and may be available for a future visitor of this Q&A.

Comment: But that was really good to know for future use, thanks a bunch for that.

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for Rolling rank to be added in pandas 1.4.0, one way to do this could be like so :

```
import pandas as pd

df[column].rolling(window).apply(lambda x: len(x[x <= x.iloc[-1]]) / len(x))
```

Where window is the `window` on which you sought to roll. This should give you the same result as if you were using `df[column].rank(pct=True)` on a dataframe equal to the window at hand.

The lambda function divides the number of occurences under or equal the last value by the total number of value, giving us the percentage of scores fall below the current row.

**Note:** Values under the window size will return `NaN`. For example the first value for a `window=2`.

---

Example :

```
n = [5, 10, 9, 7, 6, 9, 4]
df = pd.DataFrame(n, columns=['Scores'])
df['rank_result'] = df['Scores'].rank(pct=True)
df['rolling_apply'] = df['Scores'].rolling(7).apply(lambda x: len(x[x <= x.iloc[-1]]) / len(x))
print(df[6:7]) # get the last row to compare
```

This will give the following output for the last row :

```
   Scores  rank_result  rolling_apply
6       4     0.142857       0.142857
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that alternative. But the way you did it is with the Lambda Function. I have attempted this right now with the regular function and using apply ( ). But when i run the code, it outputs 0's in the column. Since i can't put the code here in the comment section in the readable code format, and it slightly different from the original question i posted, i have posted another question for this. Look at following link, https://stackoverflow.com/q/70358306/5315363

Comment: Sure, i'll have a look!