# Rolling Percentile Function outputting 0's in column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation, percentile

When creating a function, and using rolling( ) with the apply( ) to calculate a rolling 3 day percentile distribution, it is displaying 0's after the first 3 days for the rest of the Column.

I'm assuming that the first 2 days which have NaN Values are not being used in the calculation of the percentile function, and therefore maybe defaulting the rest of the columns to Zero, and incorrectly giving the 33 value for the third day. But im not sure about this.

I have been trying to solve this, but have not got any solution. Does anybody know why and how to solve correct this code below ? it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
```

```
data = { 'a': [1, 15, 27, 399, 17, 568, 200, 9], 
         'b': [2, 30, 15, 60, 15, 80, 53, 41],
         'c': [100,200, 3, 78, 25, 88, 300, 91],
         'd': [4, 300, 400, 500, 23, 43, 9, 71]
         }

dfgrass = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
def percnum(x):
    for t in dfgrass.index:
        aaa = (x<=dfgrass.loc[t,'b']).value_counts()
        ccc = (x<=dfgrass.loc[t, 'b']).values.sum()
        vvv = len(x)
        nnn = ccc/ vvv
        return nnn * 100

dfgrass['e'] = dfgrass['b'].rolling(window=3).apply(percnum)
print(dfgrass)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option for what you are attempting is to directly apply pandas' [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) method with `pct=True` in your function. This will run the percentile method directly on the subset defined by the rolling window. This can be done like so:

```
def rolling_percentile(x):
    d = pd.DataFrame(x)
    d['rolling'] = d.rank(pct=True)
    return d.iloc[-1, 1]
```

Then you can insert that into your apply:

```
df['rolling_apply'] = df[column].rolling(window).apply(rolling_percentile)
```

---

**Additional notes on the function:** There are other ways to do this, but within the function I create a `rolling` column on subset `x` of the initial dataframe. Since for each `x` a window is passed with n amount of previous values. For example if you window is of three, a numpy array will be passed looking a little like this : `[1, 15, 27]`.
Hence, the rolling percentage that interests us is the one of the last value of `x` relative to the values contained within the window. Therefore we get that value at position [-1, 1] which corresponds to the `rolling` column of the last value.

Comment: Thank you Very Much !!! . I have two questions, (1) inside the function for  " d['rolling'] ", did you mean to put instead the newly created column df['rolling_apply'] ?      (2) for "return d.iloc[-1, 1]", the syntax here would be to output the last value in the column B. But im not exactly clear of its purpose and how it works in the function, is the purpose that its used like a stopping point for the calculation for the rows in the column ? or does it serve something else ?

Comment: Yes sorry, let me make that clear in the post :)

Comment: Let me know if the edit makes sense

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful clarification. But there is some further clarification i want to address with the function. But before i comment on that, i need to know if the variable of the dataframe "d" that you put in the function for the data frame as d=pd.DataFrame(x) , d['rolling'], d.rank(pct=true),  are they suppose to be using "df" as the noted variable for the dataframe ? so it would be  df=pd.DataFrame(x), df=['rolling'], df.rank(pct=True).    If so, can you edit the answer with that please ?

Comment: no, d is a separate dataframe created just with the subset of df you are passing within the window. So it should be named something other than df which is already used and it is only used within that function call

Comment: don' hesitate to mark the answer as valid if it has solved your problem

Comment: Sorry, yes i was going to do that today. Really appreciate it.  I have further comment below,

Comment: Fredaroo, the function you put here for Rolling Percentile Distribution, in my opinion looking at all other solutions here in stack exchange, your solution here is the most efficient in terms of number of lines of code and most simplest !, and benefit of still using the rank(pct=True) method. The few lines of code here was beautiful, a masterpiece of code here ! Thankyou for the clear clarification and assistance ! Cheers !

Comment: No worries, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try changing `for t in dfgrass.index` to `for t in x.index` in your implementation of `def percnum(x)` like so:

```
def percnum(x):
    for t in x.index:
        aaa = (x<=dfgrass.loc[t,'b']).value_counts()
        ccc = (x<=dfgrass.loc[t, 'b']).values.sum()
        vvv = len(x)
        nnn = ccc/ vvv
        return nnn * 100
```

Comment: Thanks !!, the Zeros in the Column are now filled in with Values. But the first value 33 % is an incorrect values, it is still there, and the rest of the Percentage values that got filled in the column, seem to be lagged 1 Value backwards, and the last 2 rows seem to be lagged 2 values backwards. When i say backwards, i mean for example the last value in the column is showing percentage 100%, but this is inocrrect beause it is taking the value from 2 rows before it in the column.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you're trying to do, and what you want the expected output is? Thanks.

Comment: it is a rolling percentile distribution. the problem is its giving me wrong value. The Code above is outputting 33 % as the first value , when it should be 66 %.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to compute the percentile ranks, then you can try something like

```
def percnum(x):
    n = len(x)
    temp = x.argsort()
    ranks = np.empty(n)
    ranks[temp] = (np.arange(n) + 1) / n
    return ranks[-1]

dfgrass.rolling(3).apply(percnum)
```

which gives the following output

```
          a         b         c         d
0       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2  1.000000  0.666667  0.333333  1.000000
3  1.000000  1.000000  0.666667  1.000000
4  0.333333  0.666667  0.666667  0.333333
5  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  0.666667
6  0.666667  0.666667  1.000000  0.333333
7  0.333333  0.333333  0.666667  1.000000
```

Comment: But what is the purpose of the "return ranks[-1]"  here ? i know it returns the last value, but what is the purpose here in the in the forumula and code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas `rolling` function combined with `quantile` as follows. Enter any quantile value between 0 and 1 (ie your percentile/100). If you don't want Nans at the beginning, set `min_periods` to 1.

```
data = { 'a': [1, 15, 27, 399, 17, 568, 200, 9], 
         'b': [2, 30, 15, 60, 15, 80, 53, 41],
         'c': [100,200, 3, 78, 25, 88, 300, 91],
         'd': [4, 300, 400, 500, 23, 43, 9, 71]
         }
dfgrass = pd.DataFrame(data)
rolling_percentile=dfgrass.rolling(window=3,min_periods=1,center=False,axis=0).quantile(0.4)
print(rolling_percentile)
```

which gives the following output:

```
       a     b      c      d
0    1.0   2.0  100.0    4.0
1    6.6  13.2  140.0  122.4
2   12.2  12.4   80.6  240.8
3   24.6  27.0   63.0  380.0
4   25.0  15.0   20.6  324.6
5  322.6  51.0   67.4   39.0
6  163.4  45.4   75.4   20.2
7  161.8  50.6   90.4   36.2
```